# Display Header Text on generated PDF with FPDF

Tags: php

i am using FPDF to Generate Report to PDF file and it work but what i want is to print the name from variable to the title of the report can any body tell me how to accomplish this

my variable to printed on the header is username of the person which the report is generated i try like this but it do not work

```php
<?php 
$username=$_POST['username'];

function Header()
{

    $name="Export PDF";
    $this->SetFont('Arial','B',10);
    $this->Image('images/pdflogo.png', 5,5,60);
    $this->Image('images/hr1.jpg', 10,25,190);
    $this->Text(100,25,'Weekly Report for user'.$username);

    $this->Cell(80);

    $this->SetFont('Arial','B',9);

    $this->Ln(20);
}
```

EDIT: full code Below

```
class PDF extends FPDF {

    function Header() {

        $name = "Export PDF";
        $this->SetFont( 'Arial', 'B', 10 );
        $this->Image( 'images/pdflogo.png', 5, 5, 60 );
        $this->Image( 'images/hr1.jpg', 10, 25, 190 );
        $this->Text( 100, 25, 'Weekly Report'.$username );

        $this->Cell( 80 );

        $this->SetFont( 'Arial', 'B', 9 );

        $this->Ln( 20 );
    }


    function Footer() {
        $this->Image( 'images/hr1.jpg', 10, 280, 190 );
    }


    function LoadData( $file ) {

        $lines = file( $file );
        $data  = array();
        foreach ( $lines as $line ) {
            $data[ ] = explode( ';', chop( $line ) );
        }

        return $data;
    }


    function BasicTable( $header, $data ) {

        $this->SetFillColor( 255, 255, 255 );
        $this->SetDrawColor( 0, 0, 0 );
        $w = array( 20, 30, 25, 23, 30, 30, 30, 12, 30 );


        for ( $i = 0; $i < count( $header ); $i++ ) {
            $this->Cell( $w[ $i ], 7, $header[ $i ], 1, 0, 'C', true );
        }
        $this->Ln();


        foreach ( $data as $eachResult ) { //width

            $this->Cell( 20, 6, $eachResult[ "issue_title" ], 1 );
            $this->Cell( 30, 6, $eachResult[ "department" ], 1 );
            $this->Cell( 25, 6, $eachResult[ "submitted_by" ], 1 );
            $this->Cell( 23, 6, $eachResult[ "date" ], 1 );
            $this->Cell( 30, 6, $eachResult[ "solution_g" ], 1 );
            $this->Cell( 30, 6, $eachResult[ "t_status" ], 1 );
            $this->Cell( 30, 6, $eachResult[ "date_solved" ], 1 );

            $this->Ln();

        }
    }

}

$pdf = new PDF();
$header = array(
    'Issue Title',
    'Department',
    'Submited By',
    'Date',
    'Solution Given',
    'Ticket Status',
    'Date of Solved'
);
//Data loading
//*** Load MySQL Data ***//
$objConnect = mysql_connect( "localhost", "root", "" ) or die( "Error:Please check your database username & password" );
$objDB = mysql_select_db( "helpdesk_ticket" );
$strSQL = "SELECT issue_title, department,submitted_by,date,solution_g,t_status,date_solved FROM allocated_task where assigned_user ='$assigned_user' and date >= '$fyear-$fmonth-$fday' AND date <= '$tyear-$tmonth-$tday' ";
$objQuery = mysql_query( $strSQL );
$resultData = array();
for ( $i = 0; $i < mysql_num_rows( $objQuery ); $i++ ) {
    $result = mysql_fetch_array( $objQuery );
    array_push( $resultData, $result );
}
//************************//


function forme() {

}


$pdf->SetFont( 'Arial', '', 6 );

//*** Table 1 ***//

$pdf->AddPage();
//$pdf->Image('images/pdflogo.png',20,8,83);
//$pdf->Ln(15);

$pdf->BasicTable( $header, $resultData );
forme();
$pdf->Output( "$d.pdf", "F" );
$rep_count = mysql_query( $strSQL );
$con = mysql_num_rows( $rep_count );
```

Comment: i use FPDF class to generate the PDF

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `global $username;` to your `Header` method in the `PDF` class so that it would actually work in your code. Usually I would define a special field for the username in the class as I believe it's a better practice. Something like this

```
class PDF extends FPDF {

    private $username;

    public function getUsername(){
        return $this->username;
    }

    public function setUsername($username){
        $this->username;
    }
    // the rest of your code

}
```

And then just use the `$this->username` in the class instead of defining `global $username;`

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your function is a method of a Class, then the $username property should be accessed with the $this...

```
$this->Text(100,25,'Weekly Report for user'.$this->username);
```

But in this case, I think the username value should be affected in a different way than directly at the property initialization, because the $_POST value is out of the Class. Something like this :

```
$object = new YourClass();
$object->username = $_POST['username'];
```

UPDATE:

As you edited your code, I don't see your call to the header() method.
But you can pass the username value as a method param like this :

```
    function Header($username){
        ...

        $this->Text(100,25,'Weekly Report for user'.$username);
    }
```

or add a property in your PDF Class and access it with the `this` keyword as I said above:

```
class PDF extends FPDF
{
public $username ="";
...
...
$this->Text(100,25,'Weekly Report'.$this->username);
```